# rodents eating fig cuttings in my greenhouse

Tags: diagnosis, pests, pest-damage, greenhouse, rodents

I am having a problem with something getting into my greenhouse at night and eating my fig cuttings down to the nubs! It is also eating my plastic containers? what is it?  I checked the perimeter of the greenhouse and found a tiny opening.  It's too small for raccoons to get in, are rats the probable culprits?

Comment: I'd guess mice. They can squeeze through openings of a mere fraction of an inch.

Comment: Good question; if could include more details, including clearances around the door(s) when closed, any sorts of marks on the figs & containers, if the ceiling is enclosed, and dimensions of the hole you found, could also be helpful. We encourage you to take the [Tour], and browse through the [Help], to learn more about how the site works! Thank you! Welcome to the site!

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend using cayenne pepper, sprinkling that should solve your problem. Harmless and effective

Comment: Thank you for your answer; if could include details of how you use the cayenne pepper could also be helpful; We encourage you to take the [Tour], and browse through the [Help] to learn more about how the site works! Thank you! Welcome to the site!